# Spark SQL JSON dataset query nested datastructures

Tags: json, apache-spark

I have a simple JSON dataset as below. How do I query all `parts.lock` for the `id`=`1`.

JSON:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A green door",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["home", "green"],
    "parts" : [
        {
            "lock" : "One lock",
            "key" : "single key"
        },
        {
            "lock" : "2 lock",
            "key" : "2 key"
        }
    ]
}
```

Query:

```
select id,name,price,parts.lockfrom product where id=1
```

The point is if I use `parts[0].lock` it will return one row as below:

```
{u'price': 12.5, u'id': 1, u'.lock': {u'lock': u'One lock', u'key': u'single key'}, u'name': u'A green door'}
```

But I want to return all the `locks` in the `parts` structure. It will return multiple rows but that's the one I am looking for. This kind of a relational join which I want to accomplish.

Please help me with this

Comment: According to http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-SQL-JSON-dataset-query-nested-datastructures-td11841.html, [lateral view with explode](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+LateralView) seems helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.select($"id", $"name", $"price", explode($"parts").alias("elem"))
  .where("id = 1")
  .select("id", "name", "price", "elem.lock", "elem.key").show

+---+------------+-----+--------+----------+
| id|        name|price|    lock|       key|
+---+------------+-----+--------+----------+
|  1|A green door| 12.5|One lock|single key|
|  1|A green door| 12.5|  2 lock|     2 key|
+---+------------+-----+--------+----------+
```