# Spark extract nested JSON array items using purely SQL-query

Tags: apache-spark-sql

**Note**: this is NOT a duplicate of following (or several other similar discussions)

- [Spark SQL JSON dataset query nested datastructures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25224740/3679900)
- [How to use Spark SQL to parse the JSON array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49133252/3679900)
- [Querying Spark SQL DataFrame with complex types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28332494/3679900)

---

I have a `Hive` table that I must read and **process purely via `Spark`-SQL-query**. This table has a `string`-type column, that contains *`JSON` dumps from APIs*; so expectedly, it has **deeply nested stringified JSONs**.

Lets take this example (it depicts the exact depth / complexity of data that I'm trying to process)

```
{
    "key1": ..
    "key2": ..
    ..
    "bill_summary": {
        "key1": ..
        "key2": ..
        ..
        "items": [
            {
                "item": {
                    "key1": ..
                    "key2": ..
                    ..
                    "type": "item_type_1"
                    ..
                    "total_cost": 57.65
                    ..
                }
            },
            {
                "item": {
                    "key1": ..
                    "key2": ..
                    ..
                    "total_cost": 23.31
                    ..
                }
            }
            ..
            {
                "item": {
                    "key1": ..
                    "key2": ..
                    ..
                    "type": "item_type_1"
                    ..
                }
            }
        ]
        ..
    }
    ..
}
```

I'm interested in the `items` array. I'm able to access it via

```
get_json_object(get_json_object('$.bill_summary'), '$.items') AS items
```

Now here's the problem

- I need to take out all (`type`, `total_cost`) tuples from the array
- But I only need those entries where both these are present, whereas several `item` objects have either of those or none of them

---

- While I've also managed to separately pick all `type` fields and `total_cost` fields into *two separate arrays*, but due to second limitation above (absent fields), I end up *loosing the relationship*.
- What I get (using following snippet) in the end are two arrays (possibly of different lengths), but with no certainty that *corresponding elements of each array belong to same item or not*

*this snippet lists only part of my rather long SQL-query. It employs [CTE](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Common+Table+Expression)*

```
..
split(get_json_object(get_json_object(var6, '$.bill_summary'), '$.items[*].item.type'), ',') AS types_array,
split(get_json_object(get_json_object(var6, '$.bill_summary'), '$.items[*].item.total_cost'), ',') AS total_cost_array
..
```

---

Now here are the limitations

- I have no control over source `Hive` table schema or its data
- I want to do this using **purely `Spark`SQL-query**
- I **cannot use `DataFrame` manipulation**
- I do not want to employ a [registered `udf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41331005/3679900) (I'm keeping that as a last resort)

---

I've spent several hours on docs and forums, but the [Spark-SQL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html) are sparse and [discussions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36850870/3679900) mostly revolve around `DataFrame` API, which I cannot use. Is this problem even solvable by SQL-query alone?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After hours of scouring the web, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620811/3679900) answer hinted me that I can **cast a *stringified* JSON array to array of structs** in spark-sql. Finally here's what I did

```
     ..
     var6_items AS
  (SELECT hash_id,
          entity1,
          dt,
          get_json_object(get_json_object(var6,'$.bill_summary'), '$.items[*].item') AS items_as_string
   FROM rows_with_appversion
   WHERE appversion >= 14),

     filtered_var6_items AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM var6_items
   WHERE items_as_string IS NOT NULL
     AND items_as_string != '')

    SELECT from_json(items_as_string, 'array<struct<type:string,total_cost:string>>') AS items_as_struct_array
    FROM filtered_var6_items
     ..
```

---

explanation

- the expression `get_json_object(get_json_object(var6,'$.bill_summary'), '$.items[*].item') AS items_as_string` results in `items_as_string` containing following (stringified) JSON (note that one level of redundant nesting around each `item` has also been removed)

> ```
> [
>   {
>     "key1": "val1",
>     "key2": "val2",
>     "type": "item_type_1",
>     "total_cost": 57.65
>   },
>   {
>     "key1": "val1",
>     "key2": "val2",
>     "total_cost": 57.65
>   }
>   ..
>   {
>     "key1": "val1",
>     "key2": "val2",
>     "type": "item_type_1"
>   }
> ]
> ```

- thereafter, `from_json` function allows casting the above structure into an `array` of `structs`. Once that is obtained, I can [`filter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#filter) structs that have both `type` and `total_cost` as not `NULL`

---

References

- Spark-SQL's [`from_json` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#from_json)
- [`user6910411`'s answer to How to cast an array of struct in a spark dataframe using selectExpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51620811/3679900)

Comment: thank you for sharing. one question: is there a reason why it's a `get_json_object()` inside of another `get_json_object()`?